# Finding the image of the function $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R, \; f(x)=\frac{2x}{x^2+1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I am studying calculus and I have a question about finding the image of a function. Is there an efficient way to do it? I stumbled upon a function I had a hard time finding it's image:

$$f(x)=\frac{2x}{x^2+1} ,(x\in \mathbb{R})$$

Please explain how we can find the image of $f(x)$ .

Thanks in advance .

---

Edit : I tried isolating $x$ and find the domain of $x$, under the assumption $f(x)$ is invertible the domain of $f^{-1}(x)$ should be the image of $f(x)$ .

Comment: Write $\dfrac {2x}{x^2+1}=a$ and find the Discriminant $\Delta_x≥0$ . Or Divide numerator/denominator by $x≠0$ ,then use Am-Gm inequality separately for $x>0$ and $-x>0$ .

Comment: You can determine the image of a function $f$ graphically (it is the horizontal projection of the graph), or partition the domain into intervals where $f$ is continuous and monotonic, and calculate the limits of $f$ at the bounds of these intervals.

Comment: We will *not* "find the image of this function and explain the solution" before *you* show *some* work. [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes but during an exam I wont be able to have a graph..

I see, next time I will show some work. thank you

Comment: Why "next time"? You can edit your post, and use the second method (without the graph).

Comment: @AnneBauval i did edit what i tried.. 

We are not allowed to use limits / derivatives.

this is a super beginner part of the course we didnt learn anything yet in terms of limits etc

Comment: Oh I see! Then $$f(x)=y\iff yx^2-2x+y=0.$$ Now, what are the values of $y$ for which this quadratic equation has real solutions $x$?

Comment: Thank you very much! great solution @AnneBauval

Answer (score 1):

Anne Bauval has shown you one way in the comments. I would like to offer you a different way of looking at it, based on comparisons between the numerator and denominator. Let's get into it!

Suppose that the value of the numerator exceeds that of the denominator; i.e. $2x\gt x^2+1$. Solving this inequality for $x$ yields $0\gt x^2-2x+1 \Rightarrow 0\gt (x-1)^2$. But this inequality cannot be satisfied by any real value of $x$, so it is impossible for the numerator to ever be greater than the denominator, which means that $|f(x)|\leq 1$ for all $x$.

We have deduced that the magnitude of $f(x)$ can be at most $1$. All that remains is to work out whether it ever *can* equal $1$, and that is done by setting each part of the function equal to each other. If $2x=x^2+1$, this implies that $x^2-2x+1=(x-1)^2=0$. This has a solution, namely $x=1$. This means that $1$ is indeed in the image of $f(x)$, but wait: as a quotient of an odd function and an even function, we have that $f(-x)=-f(x)$. We just found that $f(x)=1$ when $x=1$; multiplying $x$ by $-1$ in this instance yields $f(-1)=-1$.

Putting it all together: we found that $f(x)$ is bounded by $-1$ and $1$. There exists no factorization of $x^2+1$ in the real numbers so there exist no discontinuities in the domain, which means that $f(x)$ achieves every value between $-1$ and $1$ for some value of $x$. The image is therefore the real interval $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Everything you said about $0$ (being it the domain, being in the image, being the limit at $\pm\infty$) is useless. It is sufficient to say that $|f(x)|\le1,$ $1$ and $-1$ are in the image, and $f$ is continuous on $\Bbb R.$

Answer (score 1):

The well-known way is to solve $\Delta_x≥0$ :

$$
\begin{align}&\frac {2x}{x^2+1}=a\\
\implies &ax^2-2x+a=0\\
\implies &\Delta_x=1-a^2≥0\end{align}
$$

---

Or use [AM-GM inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/AM-GM_Inequality) :

If $x=0$, then $f(x)=0$ .

If $x>0$, then :

$$
\begin{align}f(x)&=\frac{2x}{x^2+1}\\
&=\frac {2}{x+1/x}\\
&≤\frac{2}{2}=1\end{align}
$$

If $x<0$, then :

$$\begin{align}f(x)&=\frac{2x}{x^2+1}\\
&=-\frac {2}{-x+\left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)}\\
&≥-\frac{2}{2}=-1\end{align}$$

Since $f(x)$ is continuous everywhere, therefore $f$ takes all values at the interval $[-1,1]$ .

Thus, ${\rm{Im}}(f)\in[-1,1]$ .

Comment: 1) You (partially, forgetting to say $f(x)$ has the sign of $x$) proved $\operatorname{Im}(f)\subset[-1,1]$ (not "${\rm{Im}}(f)\in[-1,1]$ "), you didn't prove $=.$ 2) You mentionned continuity but didn't really use it. 3) AM-GM inequality is a bit overkill: $(x\pm1)^2\ge0\implies-1\le f(x)\le1.$

Comment: @AnneBauval I could not understand some points. 2) You mentioned continuity... can you elaborate please ? 3) Am-GM inequality is a bit overkill. Please, elaborate. I only understood the wrong notation $\in$, which I used .

Comment: You wrote "*Since $f(x)$ is continuous everywhere,* therefore $f$ takes all values at the interval $[-1,1]$" but the fact that $f$ takes *all its values in* the interval $[-1,1]$ does not use continuity: it only uses the inequalities you proved, plus those you forgot to mention ($f(x)>0>-1$ if $x>0$ and $f(x)<0<1$ if $x<0$). If what you meant was that $f$ takes *all the values of* the interval $[-1,1]$, continuity would be useful indeed but a second argument is missing (the proof that $f$ takes the two values $\pm1$).

Comment: AM-GM inequality is a bit overkill: to prove that $f(x)\le1,$ it suffices to check that $2x\le x^2+1$ i.e. $(x-1)^2\ge0.$ Similarly, $(x+1)^2\ge0\implies $f(x)\ge-1$.

Comment: @AnneBauval "but the fact that $f$ takes all its values in the interval $[−1,1]$
 does not use continuity: **it only uses the inequalities you proved"** How about  $$f(x)=\frac {x^2+1}{x^2+2}+\frac {x^2+2}{x^2+1}≥2.$$ Can $f(x)$ take *all values*, which greater than $2$ ?

Comment: You seem to mix the two distinct sentences which I though clearly distinguished: $f$
 *takes all its values in* the interval  (which **doesn't use continuity**), and $f$
 *takes all the values of* the interval (which uses continuity plus another argument).

Comment: First note that, I appreciate discussion, since I learn something new things.  Yes . Proving $f(x)≤1$ and $f(x)≥-1$ is indeed trivial. But, here I *derived* $-1≤f(x)≤1$, rather than I *proved* . Right ? @AnneBauval The AM-GM inequality holds iff, when $x^2=1$ , which implies $f(x)$ takes $-1$, if $x=-1<0$ and $1$ of $x=1>0$ .

Comment: I wrote , for instance if $x<0$ then $$\begin{align}f(x)&=\frac{2x}{x^2+1}\\
&=-\frac {2}{-x+\left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)}\\
&≥-\frac{2}{2}=-1\end{align}$$ Can you elaborate again please 
 *exactly*, what is incorrect here ? @AnneBauval

Comment: Sorry, I am not so good in english, I don't understand the difference between *proving* and *deriving*. What you derived *explicitely* from AM-GM is only $x\ge0\implies f(x)\le1$ (not $f(x)\ge-1$), and $x\le0\implies f(x)\ge-1$ (not $f(x)\le1$) I am not sure to understand what you mean in your comment after "The AM-GM inequality holds iff", I agree of course that $f(1)=1$ and $f(-1)=-1$, and this was the argument missing (in addition to continuity) to prove that $\operatorname{Im}(f)$ is equal to the interval $[-1,1],$ and not just a subset of it. In your last comment, I see nothing incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Another way .

---

Let $x=\tan \alpha$, then you have :

$$
\begin{align}\frac{2\tan\alpha }{1+\tan^2 \alpha}&=\frac {2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha}{\sin^2\alpha+\cos^2\alpha}\\
&=\sin (2\alpha)\end{align}
$$

Since $-1≤\sin (2\alpha)≤1$, you are done .

Answer (score 0):

Various methods:

1. The image of a $f$ is the horizontal projection of [its graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+2x%2F%28x%5E2%2B1%29%2C+x%3D-6+to+6).
2. $f$ is continuous and (calculate its derivative) monotonic on $(-\infty,-1],$ $[-1,1],$ and $[1,+\infty).$ Its limits at $-\infty,-1,1,+\infty$ are respectively $0,-1,1,0.$
3. $f(x)=y\iff yx^2-2x+y=0,$ and this quadratic equation has real solutions $x$ iff its discriminant $4-4y^2$ is $\ge0.$

Each of these methods allows to conclude:
$$\operatorname{Im}(f)=[-1,1].$$